# Upgrading from 3.1.3 to 4.2.0 GraphQL version

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, graphql

I am upgrading my GraphQL version from `3.1.3` to `4.2.0`. When I compile my code I am seeing below three errors -

> The type or namespace name 'EnterLeaveListener' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>
> 'IServiceProvider' does not contain a definition for 'GetRequiredService' and no accessible extension method 'GetRequiredService' accepting a first argument of type 'IServiceProvider' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>
> 'ExecutionOptions' does not contain a definition for 'FieldMiddleware' and no accessible extension method 'FieldMiddleware' accepting a first argument of type 'ExecutionOptions' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Here is my `InputValidationRule` class where `EnterLeaveListener` class is being used:

```
public class InputValidationRule : IValidationRule
{
    public Task<INodeVisitor> ValidateAsync(ValidationContext context)
    {
        return Task.FromResult((INodeVisitor)new EnterLeaveListener(_ =>
        {
        }));

        return Task.FromResult((INodeVisitor)) new 
    }
}
```

And here is my `GraphQLMiddleware` class:

```
   using GraphQL;
   using GraphQL.Instrumentation;
   using GraphQL.NewtonsoftJson;
   using GraphQL.Types;
   using GraphQL.Utilities;
   using GraphQL.Validation;
   
   public class GraphQLMiddleware
    {
        private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
        private readonly GraphQLSettings _settings;
        private readonly IDocumentExecuter _executer;
        private readonly IDocumentWriter _writer;

        public GraphQLMiddleware(
            RequestDelegate next,
            GraphQLSettings settings,
            IDocumentExecuter executer,
            IDocumentWriter writer)
        {
            _next = next;
            _settings = settings;
            _executer = executer;
            _writer = writer;
        }

        public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context, ISchema schema)
        {
            if (!IsGraphQLRequest(context))
            {
                await _next(context);
                return;
            }

            await ExecuteAsync(context, schema);
        }

        private bool IsGraphQLRequest(HttpContext context)
        {
            return context.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments(_settings.Path)
                && string.Equals(context.Request.Method, "POST", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
        }

        private async Task ExecuteAsync(HttpContext context, ISchema schema)
        {
            var request = Deserialize<GraphQLRequest>(context.Request.Body);
            var result = await _executer.ExecuteAsync(_ =>
            {
                _.Schema = schema;
                _.Query = request?.Query;
                _.OperationName = request?.OperationName;
                _.Inputs = request?.Variables.ToInputs();
                _.UserContext = _settings.BuildUserContext?.Invoke(context);
                _.ValidationRules = DocumentValidator.CoreRules.Concat(new[] { new InputValidationRule() });
                _.EnableMetrics = _settings.EnableMetrics;
                if (_settings.EnableMetrics)
                {
                    _.FieldMiddleware.Use<InstrumentFieldsMiddleware>();
                }
            });
            await WriteResponseAsync(context, result);
        }

        private async Task WriteResponseAsync(HttpContext context, ExecutionResult result)
        {
            context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
            context.Response.StatusCode = result.Errors?.Any() == true ? (int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest : (int)HttpStatusCode.OK;

            await _writer.WriteAsync(context.Response.Body, result);
        }

        public static T Deserialize<T>(Stream s)
        {
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(s))
            using (var jsonReader = new JsonTextReader(reader))
            {
                var ser = new JsonSerializer();
                return ser.Deserialize<T>(jsonReader);
            }
        }
    }
```

And here is my `TitanSchema` class:

```
using GraphQL;
using GraphQL.Types;
using GraphQL.Utilities;

public class TitanSchema : Schema
{
    public TitanSchema(IServiceProvider provider) : base(provider)
    {
        Query = provider.GetRequiredService<TitanQuery>();
        this.RegisterTypeMapping<ProtoValue, ProtoValueType>();
    }
}
```

All these three classes are showing above three problems. I tried looking online but couldn't figure it out on how to resolve these. Also not seeing any dotnet `GraphQL` Middleware example which uses newest version of GraphQL. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [graphql-dotnet upgrade guide](https://graphql-dotnet.github.io/docs/migrations/migration4#dependency-injection--getrequiredservice):

> GraphQL.Utilities.ServiceProviderExtensions has been made internal. This affects usages of its extension method GetRequiredService. Instead, reference the Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions NuGet package and use the extension method from the Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions class.

So all you need to do is to add nuget reference to `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions` package if you don't have it yet and add

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
```

to your `TitanSchema` class.

Comment: Thanks for the link. Can you provide an example on how to use that in my above code?

Comment: It helped me for my one error but how can I fix other two errors? That's where I am confuse. I recently started with C# so that's where I am confuse on how to fix those.

Comment: Just look for `EnterLeaveListener` and `FieldMiddleware` in migration guide